# HTML displays when editing Announcements. How do I change back to parsed view?

Tags: wss-3.0

Using WSS 3.0.  For some reason, the display suddenly changed from a parsed (no HTML) to full HTML when **editing** anything like announcements or wikis.  How can I get the normal (not HTML) view back?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Server 2007 and Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 the only browser with WYSIWYG editing capabilities of rich-text fields is Internet Explorer.

If you use any other browser like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc. you will get a simple text field with HTML tags instead of the rich editing experience.

This behavior changes slightly in SharePoint 2010 and 2013 and you are now able to also use Chrome, Firefox and Safari to edit the enhanced rich-text field like the one used with Announcement lists.

However, the simple rich-text field like used in a Tasks list still renders HTML tags in SharePoint 2010 and 2013.